# ERROR in ./src/client-app/index.js - Module build failed: Error: Cannot find module '@babel/core'

Tags: windows, reactjs, webpack, babeljs, webpack-dev-server

I am trying to run an app written in React and Webpack and webpack-dev-server too. I'm using Windows. I'm using: Node v8.9.4 Npm v5.6.0 Webpack v3.11.0 Webpack-dev-server v2.9.1
I am executing this command to start the app:

```
"start": "webpack-dev-server --config webpack/config/dev.config.js --open",
```

I installed all this dependencies (package.json file) with `npm install` and Webpack starting to run, but it failed wit this error:

```
c:\test-dev3\name_app>npm run start
npm info it worked if it ends with ok
npm verb cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
npm verb cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
npm verb cli   'run',
npm verb cli   'start' ]
npm info using npm@5.6.0
npm info using node@v8.9.4
npm verb run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
npm info lifecycle name_app@1.0.0~prestart: name_app@1.0.0
npm info lifecycle name_app@1.0.0~start: name_app@1.0.0

> name_app@1.0.0 start c:\test-dev3\name_app
> webpack-dev-server --config webpack/config/dev.config.js --open

Project is running at http://localhost:8080/
webpack output is served from /assets
Content not from webpack is served from ./dist
404s will fallback to /index.html
webpack: wait until bundle finished: /assets/bundle.js
Hash: e5afd651a3e015181387
Version: webpack 3.11.0
Time: 1630ms
                        Asset       Size  Chunks                    Chunk Names
images/login-background-8.jpg     140 kB          [emitted]
                    bundle.js     329 kB       0  [emitted]  [big]  main
images/login-background-2.jpg     294 kB          [emitted]  [big]
images/login-background-4.jpg     428 kB          [emitted]  [big]
images/login-background-6.jpg     243 kB          [emitted]
                bundle.js.map     390 kB       0  [emitted]         main
images/login-background-3.jpg    1.41 MB          [emitted]  [big]
images/login-background-5.jpg    1.41 MB          [emitted]  [big]
images/login-background-7.jpg    1.71 MB          [emitted]  [big]
images/login-background-1.jpg     2.6 MB          [emitted]  [big]
                ../index.html  748 bytes          [emitted]
  [35] multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 ./src/client-app/index.js 40 bytes {0} [built]
  [36] (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 7.23 kB {0} [built]
  [37] ./node_modules/url/url.js 23.3 kB {0} [built]
  [39] ./node_modules/url/util.js 314 bytes {0} [built]
  [40] ./node_modules/querystring-es3/index.js 127 bytes {0} [built]
  [43] ./node_modules/strip-ansi/index.js 161 bytes {0} [built]
  [45] ./node_modules/loglevel/lib/loglevel.js 7.74 kB {0} [built]
  [46] (webpack)-dev-server/client/socket.js 1.04 kB {0} [built]
  [78] (webpack)-dev-server/client/overlay.js 3.73 kB {0} [built]
  [80] ./node_modules/html-entities/index.js 231 bytes {0} [built]
  [83] (webpack)/hot nonrecursive ^\.\/log$ 170 bytes {0} [built]
  [84] (webpack)/hot/log.js 1.04 kB {0} [optional] [built]
  [85] (webpack)/hot/emitter.js 77 bytes {0} [built]
  [86] ./node_modules/events/events.js 8.33 kB {0} [built]
  [87] ./src/client-app/index.js 1.13 kB {0} [built] [failed] [1 error]
    + 73 hidden modules

ERROR in ./src/client-app/index.js
Module build failed: Error: Cannot find module '@babel/core'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:538:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:468:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:587:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (c:\test-dev3\name_app\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js:1:75)
    at Module._compile (module.js:643:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:654:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:556:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:499:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:491:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:587:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at loadLoader (c:\test-dev3\name_app\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\loadLoader.js:13:17)
    at iteratePitchingLoaders (c:\test-dev3\name_app\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:169:2)
    at runLoaders (c:\test-dev3\name_app\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:362:2)
    at NormalModule.doBuild (c:\test-dev3\name_app\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:182:3)
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 ./src/client-app/index.js
Child html-webpack-plugin for "..\index.html":
     1 asset
       [0] ./node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js!./index.html 1.1 kB {0} [built]
       [1] ./node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js 540 kB {0} [built]
       [2] (webpack)/buildin/global.js 509 bytes {0} [built]
       [3] (webpack)/buildin/module.js 517 bytes {0} [built]
webpack: Failed to compile.
```

In all research, they said I just to installed and config the .babelrc file with the presets. I don't know if I need to do something more with Babel and where to start. The application I didn't make it. I just to try run the app.

Also I installed other global dependencies:

```
npm install -g eslint

npm install -g webpack

npm install -g webpack-dev-server

npm install -g babel

npm install -g babel-core

npm install -g babel-cli

npm install -g babel-eslint

npm install react react-dom

npm install --save-dev webpack-dev-middleware webpack-hot-middleware
```

package.json:

```
        {
          "name": "name_app",
          "version": "1.0.0",
          "description": "",
          "main": "index.js",
          "scripts": {
            "test": "",
            "lint": "eslint src webpack --cache",
            "start": "babel-node webpack-dev-server --config webpack/config/dev.config.js --open",
          },
          "repository": {
            "type": "git",
            "url": ""
          },
          "author": "",
          "license": "",
          "bugs": {
            "url": ""
          },
          "homepage": "",
          "eslintIgnore": [
            "**/node_modules/**",
            "**/dist/**"
          ],
          "devDependencies": {
            "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
            "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
            "babel-eslint": "^8.0.1",
            "babel-loader": "^8.0.0-beta.0",
            "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
            "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
            "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
            "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.3.1",
            "css-loader": "^0.28.7",
            "eslint": "^4.7.2",
            "eslint-config-airbnb": "^15.1.0",
            "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.7.0",
            "eslint-plugin-jest": "^21.12.2",
            "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^5.1.1",
            "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.4.0",
            "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.1",
            "file-loader": "^1.1.6",
            "html-webpack-harddisk-plugin": "^0.1.0",
            "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.30.1",
            "node-sass": "^4.5.3",
            "rimraf": "^2.6.2",
            "sass-loader": "^6.0.6",
            "style-loader": "^0.19.0",
            "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^0.4.6",
            "url-loader": "^0.6.2",
            "webpack": "^3.11.0",
            "webpack-dev-server": "^2.9.1"
          },
          "dependencies": {
        "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
        "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
        "babel-eslint": "^8.0.1",
        "babel-loader": "^8.0.0-beta.0",
        "babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^6.18.0",
        "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
        "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
        "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
        "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
        "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.3.1",
        "css-loader": "^0.28.7",
        "eslint": "^4.7.2",
        "eslint-config-airbnb": "^15.1.0",
        "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.7.0",
        "eslint-plugin-jest": "^21.12.2",
        "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^5.1.1",
        "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.4.0",
        "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.1",
        "file-loader": "^1.1.6",
        "html-webpack-harddisk-plugin": "^0.1.0",
        "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.30.1",
        "node-sass": "^4.5.3",
        "rimraf": "^2.6.2",
        "sass-loader": "^6.0.6",
        "style-loader": "^0.19.0",
        "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^0.4.6",
        "url-loader": "^0.6.2",
        "webpack": "^3.11.0",
        "webpack-dev-server": "^2.9.1"      
        }
  }
```

dev.config.js:

```
var CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
var HtmlWebpackHarddiskPlugin = require('html-webpack-harddisk-plugin');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var path = require('path');
var OutputFiles = require('../output-files');

module.exports = {
  entry: OutputFiles.entryDev,
  output: {
    filename: OutputFiles.bundle,
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, OutputFiles.distPath),
    publicPath: OutputFiles.publicPath,
    libraryTarget: 'umd',
    library: ['FF', 'CMS']
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: "babel-loader" }
    ],
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: 'css-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [
          { loader: 'style-loader' }, // creates style nodes from JS strings
          {
            loader: 'css-loader', // translates CSS into CommonJS
            query: {
              modules: true,
              sourceMap: true,
              importLoaders: 1,
              // localIdentName: '[local]__[hash:base64:5]',
              localIdentName: '[local]'
            }
          },
          {
            loader: 'sass-loader',
            options: {
              includePaths: ['src/styles'], // compiles Sass to CSS
              sourceMap: true
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg|eot|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          limit: 10000,
          name: 'assets/images/[name].[ext]'
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
   new CopyWebpackPlugin([{ from: 'static' }]),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      filename: '../index.html',
      template: 'index.html',
      inject: 'head',
      alwaysWriteToDisk: true
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackHarddiskPlugin()
  ],
  devtool: 'source-map',
  devServer: {
    contentBase: './dist',
    historyApiFallback: true
  }
};
```

index.js:

```
import { render, unmountComponentAtNode } from 'react-dom';

import EventEmitter from 'events';
import React from 'react';
import app from './cms-app';
import { load as optionsLoad } from './options';

export default function compose(options) {
  const emitter = new EventEmitter();
  const cmsOptions = optionsLoad(options);

  const container = document.querySelector(options.selector);
  console.log(container);
  const CMSApp = app(emitter, cmsOptions);

  return {
    render() {
      render(<CMSApp />, container);
    },
    on(event, handler) {
      return emitter.on(event, handler);
    },
    off(event, handler) {
      return handler
        ? emitter.removeListener(event, handler)
        : emitter.removeAllListeners(event);
    },
    dispose() {
      emitter.removeAllListeners();
      return unmountComponentAtNode(container);
    }
  };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the ways to solve this is to create a `.babelrc` file in the root directory where your `webpack.config.js` file is and add :

```
{
  "presets": ["react", "es2015", "stage-0"]
}
```

As currently [babel-preset-react](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-preset-react) , [babel-preset-es2015](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-preset-es2015) and [babel-preset-stage-0](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-preset-stage-0) are already installed in your dev and project dependencies

Comment: I have this presets in the .babelrc and I get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove all `dependencies` from `package.json`, leave only `devDependencies`, since they are compile time dependencies needed purely for development purposes.
2. remove node_modules folder.
3. `npm install` again.
4. Replace start script in `package.json` with `"start": "webpack-dev-server --config webpack/config/dev.config.js --open"`, you don't need to execute `webpack-dev-server` with `babel-node`, since you already instruct webpack to run babel for you.

P. S. you don't need globally installed npm packages as dependencies, the local ones are enough, since their version is tied to specific project. Global ones can be helpful though in cases when you need global project generators like yeoman or create-react-app.

Comment: I did all steps, but I get the same error result. What is the app try load some file?